# matlab standalone executable does not open excel file

Tags: excel, matlab

I developed a simple Matlab GUI. When user hits the "upload data" button it asks if user has formatted his data or not. If user hits "NO"  it provides sample input as an excel file using winopen function.

Afterwards, I compiled this gui using deploytool. I added the excel file as "file required for your application to run". However, it does not open the excel file when user clicks "NO". Intuitively I think it should be possible to do that. Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

In other words, this line: winopen('./input_example.xlsx') is not working when I compiled my code even though I added  input_example.xlsx' to package.

Answer (score 0):

From the matlab documentation I believe you need to use full paths:

> When using winopen in deployed mode:
>
> - Verify that the file being passed to the command exists on the MATLAB path.
> - Use the which command to return an absolute path to the file.
> - Pass the path to winopen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the excel file in `Files installed for your end user`? The excel file will appear in the same folder with your `.exe` file.